# Can't start Unity project, none of the scripts load and materials are pink: JSON parse error: The document is empty

Tags: unity, visual-studio, json

I am trying to open a project from a company, the problem is, nobody has this problem except me, so one can replicate it.

When i open the project i get the following issues:

[image]

There seems to be a file that it cannot be parsed, which makes none of the components to be loaded, an a visual studio solution to not be created. I do not have any sln's, so i cannot  make or edit any scripts.

I have both Visual Studio Editor and Visual Studio Code Editor. Everytime i tried to reinstall any of these, the JSON parse error would pop up again.

When i go to External Tools in Preferences, Microsoft Visual Studio shows as (Internal) instead of it's actual version.[image]

My theory is that this JSON file error, that i cannot track what file is from, does not let me generate any csproj or sln, which does not let me start the project. Regenerate project files is also not an option either.

This is the full error, but i cannot make anything out of it.

> ArgumentException: JSON parse error: The document is empty.
> UnityEditor.EditorJsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite (System.String json, System.Object objectToOverwrite) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.UnityBeeDriver.RecreateDagDirectoryIfNeeded (NiceIO.NPath dagDirectory) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.UnityBeeDriver.BuildRequestFor (Bee.BeeDriver.RunnableProgram buildProgram, System.String dagName, System.String dagDirectory, System.Boolean useScriptUpdater, System.String projectDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ILPostProcessingProgram ilpp, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.UnityBeeDriver+CacheMode cacheMode, Bee.BeeDriver.StdOutMode stdoutMode, Bee.BeeDriver.RunnableProgram beeBackendProgram) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.UnityBeeDriver.BuildRequestFor (Bee.BeeDriver.RunnableProgram buildProgram, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation editorCompilation, System.String dagName, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.UnityBeeDriver+CacheMode cacheMode, System.String dagDirectory, System.Boolean useScriptUpdater) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScriptsWithSettings (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssemblySettings scriptAssemblySettings) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScripts (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorScriptCompilationOptions editorScriptCompilationOptions, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup platformGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget platform, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String[] extraScriptingDefines) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.TickCompilationPipeline (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorScriptCompilationOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup platformGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget platform, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String[] extraScriptingDefines, System.Boolean allowBlocking) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface.TickCompilationPipeline (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorScriptCompilationOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup platformGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget platform, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String[] extraScriptingDefines, System.Boolean allowBlocking) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface:TickCompilationPipeline(EditorScriptCompilationOptions, BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, Int32, String[], Boolean)

Starting other projects seem to work, but this one specifically just doesn't. I tried reinstalling the unity version (2022.3.5), reinstalling visual studio, the visual studio tools for unity on both ends, and nothing works.

Does anyone know what this could be? thanks in advance!

Comment: For the time being, consider renaming that file to .txt. It'll likely break a lot of things but may allow you to get as far as an IDE. Failing that, you could always move the entire Crazy Minnow / Lipsync folder elsewhere, but if you do this, be sure not to save your project as broken references may not be preserved when you move it back.

Comment: Do you get the same error when making an empty project? And afterwards just adding that plugin?

Comment: If it happens only for you, with the same project files, that could be a sign of a corrupted Unity installation..I'd uninstall Unity and Visual Studi/VSCode and do a free reinstallation from.scratch, making sure you're using the same Unity version others have had success using.

Comment: @Basic the problem is i do not know what json this is to change it to a .txt, none of the error describes me where this JSON that is giving the error is located, but i would like to try if i do

Comment: @Zibelas i made a new project on the same version and it seemed to work just fine when adding visual studio

Comment: @DMGregory i tried reinstalling the unity versions and the project itself, is there anything else to reinstall even further? i  only have the unity hub and the installations themselves

Comment: In your Unity project folder, inside `..\ProjectSettings\Packages\com.unity.settings-manager\` folder, find the `settings.json` file. Copy it to a safe place & delete the original. Unity should rebuild it when needed. If "Regenerate project files is also not an option" means you can't do that, then instead get a copy of `settings.json` from someone who has a working build & put it in the aforementioned folder. [source with some other options](https://forum.unity.com/threads/json-parse-error.965777/#post-6608497)

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant renaming the editor file throwing the error (from the screenshots, it's something like `Assets/Plugins/Crazy Minnow Studio/SALSA LipSync/Editor/SALSA-LipSync-Editor.dll`, if it was text rather than a screenshot, it'd be easier to copy/paste, so there may be typos).